# Solving recurrences using substitution method

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms, data-analysis

I have given 
$$
T(n)= \begin{cases}  T(n/3)+T(2n/3)+n,\quad &n>1 \\
  1, \quad &n=1
\end{cases}
$$
I tried it again and again but couldn't think beyond,
$$                
T(n)=T(n/27)+3T(2n/27)+3T(4n/27)+T(8n/27) \\
+n/3+2n/3+n/9+8n/9+n
$$
What would be next step, if I write $27$ as $3^3$ or $3^k$?

Comment: There is a "c" in your original equation that is not in your final equation.  What happened to it?

Comment: What happens when n is not a whole number?